# Intermittent Umbraco Exception

Tags: iis-6, umbraco

This is an intermittent exception that occurs intermittently in Umbraco 3.0.4 running in IIS 6

When an umbraco user logs in and selects a document to edit occasionally they get this...

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
umbraco.controls.ContentControl.addControlNew(Property p, TabPage tp, String Caption) +242
umbraco.controls.ContentControl..ctor(Content c, publishModes CanPublish, String Id) +832
umbraco.cms.presentation.editContent.OnInit(EventArgs e) +442
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +321
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +692
```

Once the error has occurred, it will persist for every user logged in to umbraco until we restart the application pool (it's running in it's own) so it must be some global state being corrupted, but it can run for days without a problem, but then can require a number of restarts in a day.

If I debug in to the app it always works and if I run debugvw on the server in a broken state it doesn't give me any more information. (other than the HTTP referer)

There are a number of dead end posts all over the web like [this one](http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst4078_Umbraco-Content-Editor-Intermittent-Error.aspx) but none seem to provide any concrete ways to reproduce.

I know it's a long shot, but has anyone here experienced and resolved this issue?

Upgrading is unfortunately not an option at the moment.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Update Your Umbraco Instance.... Its Free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem too. But we could not resolve it. We ended up upgrading. have you maybe tried doing a minor upgrade?

Comment: Upgrading's not an option for us a the moment. Were you able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Ended up doing a minor upgrad and now works. Awarded answer in sympathy :-(